# Does Lucene.Net Sort and then filter, or filter and then sort?

Tags: sorting, filtering, lucene.net

We are using the Lucene.Net [IndexSearch.Search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Weight,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort%29) method. We are passing a filter and a Sort, but we're seeing some strange behaviour. Logic tells me that filtering would be done before sorting, for performance reasons, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

Filter then Sort.

Sorting in Lucene is done by collecting Documents in order into a queue. It keeps the top X documents, where X is the maximum number of results you asked for. The collectors wont compare documents that dont match either the `Filter` or the `Query`.

When you dont specify a Sort, the score is used to prioritize documents into the queue, if you use a Sort, a Comparator for the Sort you asked for is used instead.

If you are more curious, have a look at the different `Collector` classes in the source code, the Collect() methods have all the info you want.